# $wpdb->query() multiple query support

Tags: wpdb

Just bump into the issue that I can't execute multiple sql queries using the `$wpdb->query()`. Generated queries work fine directly in phpmyadmin so its something will the ezSQL class only. By design perhaps?

I found this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpdb-gtquery-fails-when-multiple-update-statements-are-used which also says its by design. Can anyone confirm? ezSQL docs dont say anything about multiple queries support.

If you have to do a bunch of queries mainly (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), any better way of doing them other than doing them one by one using `$wpdb->insert()` and like functions?

Comment: Interesting question, can you edit it and include a code example? This will teach more users about multiple statements in one query. Does it help to use transactions here?

Comment: What's the issue with doing them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP 5.3.5, I was unable to make this syntax work even after [setting the 5th parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669) of `mysql_connect()` to 65536 (`CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`). Looks like it's not possible to concatenate multiple queries into one statement as long as the old-school MySQL API is running the show.

I assume you're familiar with the [MySQL multiple row INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) syntax, but I mention it just in case.

Comment: Thanks for checking, looks like its mysql's fault then and not of ezSQL. Yes, I am using multiple row syntax for inserts now. I will just wait for sometime in case someone stops by and add something here before accepting your answer.